# Can't Change Visio Cells Programmatically

Tags: c#, vba, vsto, visio

I need to change a line colour of a selected shape. I have the following code:

```
selectedShape.Cells["LineColor"].FormulaU = "RGB(255,0,0)";
```

It doesn't work for some shapes, while it works flawlessly for other ones. I also tried FormulaForceU and modifying other properties besides LineColor, it was all the same, it worked for some shapes, it didn't work for some other.

The stencils are non Visio standard and unfortunately I can't post them here.

Comment: Is it safe to assume you've checked the formatting protection on the shapes where the code doesn't work?

Comment: Another possibility for this type of issue can be when the shape you're targeting might not have any geometry, or, it might have its NoLine cell set to true, and really you should be targeting a child / sub-shape.  Probably not the answer for this specific question, but worth considering for similar problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Visio stencils I used didn't allow me to overwrite that property.

Answer (score 0):

Try use like this

```
selectedShape.Cells["LineColor"].FormulaU = "\"RGB(255,0,0)\"";
```

Visio need exact quote character for the formulas.

I had similar issue with the cell . However I used ].Formula

Regards.